Rationals are incomplete and naturals are complete
Why are rationals incomplete and natural complete? I have been going through Analysis textbooks but I don't totally get the reason why.
So, naturals are complete because you can divide them into two sets in such a way that all the natural numbers are inside one and only one of the sets. Let's say that we define the cutting point in $\sqrt{2}$; then one of the sets will contain all the numbers equal or smaller than $1$ (which in the naturals will only be $1$), and the other will contain every number greater or equal than $2$.
Moving to the rational numbers, we do the same subdivision (cutting point in $\sqrt{2}$). One set contains all the rational numbers until $\sqrt{2}$ without including it and the other one all the rational numbers greater than $\sqrt{2}$ without including it. Technically, that is the reason why the rationals are incomplete.
In both of the cases we are not including $\sqrt{2}$, since it isn't either in the naturals or in the rationals. But in one case, this leads to non-completeness, and in the other one no, why?

Can you write down the definition of "complete" on which you are operating?

It is because the natural numbers consist of isolated points, so that any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant. The completeness of the naturals is not particularly interesting, in that it doesn't really tell us anything we don't already know (expressed in different language). The completeness of the real numbers, by contrast, gives us existence proofs (such as the intermediate value theorem).

Both of the answers (so far) assume that completeness is defined in terms of Cauchy sequences.  Possibly the books you consulted used instead a definition in terms of Dedekind cuts, in which case you need to check carefully what that definition says in your $\sqrt2$ example. In any case, if completeness was defined differently from the two answers, you should add the relevant definition to your question.

Edit. It turns out there exist two different definitions for completeness, and OP didn't explicitly state which definition was to be assumed (though admittedly, it should've been obvious from the context of the OP). That being said, the following response provides a sufficient answer for when Cauchy Convergence defines completeness. In due time, this response will be updated to include the Dedekind cuts variant.

In order for a metric space $X$ (if you are unfamiliar with these, just know that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ denote metric spaces) to be called complete, it must hold that for any given Cauchy sequence $(a_n)\subset X$, $a_n$ converges to limit point $a\in X$. (Take note! A sequence is Cauchy convergent if and only if it is convergent when discussing $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{N}$. This fact does not hold in general however.)
When looking at $\mathbb{Q}$, consider the sequence $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since this sequence converges to Euler's constant $e\notin\mathbb{Q}$, we conclude $\mathbb{Q}$ must not be complete. Pivoting our attention over to $\mathbb{N}$, the question can alternatively be viewed as showing that $\mathbb{N}$ is a closed subset $\subset\mathbb{R}$. This fact is easily proven seeing that $\mathbb{N}^c=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}[(n,n+1)\cup(-n-1,-n)]$ recalling that the union of open sets will always remain open.

Because that is not the criterion for completeness, and is at best a hint for it.
What you seem to be describing is the notion of Dedekind cut, which is used to define the reals beyond the rationals.
A  metric space $(M,d)$ is said to be complete if any Cauchy sequence in $M$ converges to a limit in $M$.

Recall: In case that's a bit much to throw at you:

Loosely speaking, a metric space $(M,d)$ is a set $M$ equipped with a notion of distance $d : M \times M \to [0,\infty)$ encapsulated by a metric function. This function has to satisfy the properties for all $x,y,z \in M$:

Symmetry: $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$
Positive-Definiteness: $d(x,y) \ge 0$ with $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$
Triangle Inequality: $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$


The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ with the absolute value $d(x,y) := |x-y|$ is an example of a metric space.

A sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq M$ is said to be Cauchy if, given any $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n,m \ge N$, then $d(x_n,x_m) < \varepsilon$.

Basically, this means that, if you specify how close you want your sequence members to be ($\varepsilon$), if the sequence is Cauchy, I will always be able to find an index $N$ such that, for all members after, that closeness is satisfied.

The same sequence is said to have limit $x$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,x) = 0$

In $\mathbb{R}$ with the absolute value, it is known that a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy. (This isn't true in all metric spaces though!)



From how densely packed the rationals are in $\mathbb{R}$, then, it is easy to find sequences which would converge (in $\mathbb{R}$, but not $\mathbb{Q}$!) to elements not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Just pick your favorite irrational $x$, and then define the sequence
$$
x_n :=  \frac{\lfloor 10^n x \rfloor}{10^n}
$$
This just gets you the first ever-so-many digits of $x$'s decimal expansion. (Play with it here.)
Now the difficulty is: can you find a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ that converges? It is so very not dense: you'll find it impossible to construct a sequence of naturals that converges at all unless it is eventually constant! (We do not include divergence to $+\infty$.)
To see this, note that the definition of convergence of $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ requires, essentially, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, for there to be
infinitely many $x_n$ "trapped" within a distance of $\varepsilon$ of the claimed limit $x$ (namely, at least all of the $x_n$ when $n > N$ in the definition). But you can't have any naturals within, say, $\varepsilon = \frac 1 2$ of any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ - except $k$ itself.
So if a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ converges, it is eventually a constant sequence, and hence Cauchy. Hence, $\mathbb{N}$ is complete.
